# Calls to `composer install` should only ever use satis dist zip files, never source

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, satis

We're using a satis repo to host zip file dependencies. Our composer.json file's repository array points to the satis repo and disables packagist. But when we run composer update, composer.lock still lists the original source under "source" (The one listed in satis.json under repositories). The satis is listed under "dist". Which is a problem because a call to composer install will download the source.

How can I have calls to composer install only download the satis dist zip file and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were having the exact same problem you describe. We managed to get our to work by removing `"skip-dev": true` (we had that in there while troubleshooting) and running `composer update` with `--prefer-dist` option.

Not sure exactly how all of this is put together, brand new to satis and still learning composer. Hope this helps someone in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

If you do have an old `composer.lock` file that was created prior to setting up Satis and disabling access to Packagist, this is normal.

And simply trying to update with an existing installation loaded the wrong way will also persist. If you want to start over completely new, delete both `composer.lock` and the `vendor` folder and run `composer update`. To be extra sure, `composer update --prefer-dist`.

If this still does not do what you want, you probably have to take a look at the dependencies' versions. Are there any branches required?

And the other thing is how you configured your Satis instance. I am running one for a year or so that uses a two-step process to grab both external repositories, as well as local ones, and it works great. Maybe you can add some more detail on this.

Comment: Can you please go into more details about this?: "I am running one for a year or so that uses a two-step process to grab both external repositories, as well as local ones, and it works great."